# Java Android - Room with multiple databases for each user logged in

Tags: java, android, sql, android-studio, android-room

I'm creating an app with a local database using Room. Every user have an option to create a 'Group' model, and these Groups are displayed in the main feed.
The groups are stored in the database, but when the user logs out and then logs in with a different account he can still see the previous account groups.
How can I fix that? Is there a way to implement the database so that after calling the logout function the DB will swap to a different DB?

Thanks.

Comment: Clear specific tables related to user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I fix that?

2 Ways (at least) as will be shown

> Is there a way to implement the database so that after calling the logout function the DB will swap to a different DB?

Yes. However I'd suggest that it is not the best way and is a little more complicated than the "Universal way".

**Universal Way** - Recommended approach

Have a single Database the log include the user (userId) as a column in the log and showing just the logs for the current user.

**Mulltiple** or **UserOnly** approach

You have at least 3 databases one for the User's so they can login and a database for each use with the log table. Switching between users makes this more complex as it requires opening another database when the user is switched. Unless using arrays (why would you? (rhetoric)) then if switching from a user to another then you should ideally close the first user's database.

**Working Example**

The following is a working example/demo that utilises BOTH approaches.

Hopefully the comments and names used explain.

The Entities first :-

**User** (common to both approaches) :-

```
@Entity
class User {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long userId;
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    String userName;
    String userPassword;

    public User(){};

    @Ignore
    public User(Long userId, String userName, String userPassword) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
    }

    @Ignore
    public User(String userName, String userPassword) {
        this(null,userName,userPassword);
    }

    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public String getUserPassword() {
        return userPassword;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public void setUserPassword(String userPassword) {
        this.userPassword = userPassword;
    }
}
```

**UserLog** (common to both approaches)

```
@Entity(tableName = "log")
class UserLog {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long id;
    Long timestamp;
    Long userId;
    String logData;

    public UserLog(){}

    @Ignore
    public UserLog(User user, String logData) {
        this.id = null;
        this.timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.userId = user.getUserId();
        this.logData = logData;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public Long getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public Long getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }
    public String getLogData() {
        return logData;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public void setTimestamp(Long timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }
    public void setLogData(String logData) {
        this.logData = logData;
    }
}
```

- That's the Entities and both are common to each approach.

Now the Dao's

**UniversalDao** (for the recommended approach)

```
@Dao
interface UniversalDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    long insertUser(User user);
    @Insert
    long insertLog(UserLog userLog);
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE userId=:userId")
    User getUserById(long userId);
    @Query("SELECT * FROM log WHERE userId=:userId")
    List<UserLog> getUserLogs(long userId);
    @Query("SELECT userId FROM user WHERE userName=:userName AND userPassword=:password")
    long verifyUserLogin(String userName, String password);
}
```

- The **getuserLogs** Dao being used for getting and showing a specific user's logs.

**UserOnlyDao**

```
@Dao
interface UserOnlyDao {
    @Insert
    long insertUserLog(UserLog userLog);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM Log")
    List<UserLog> getUserLogs();

}
```

- simpler BUT ....

The Database (@Database) classes utilsing singletons

**UniversalUserDatabase** (all-in-one database approach - Recommended)

```
@Database(entities = {User.class,UserLog.class},version = 1)
abstract class UniversalUserDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract UniversalDao getAllDao();

    private static UniversalUserDatabase instance;

    static UniversalUserDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context,
                    UniversalUserDatabase.class,"universaluser.db"
            ).allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

- Pretty straightforward

**UserOnlyDatabase** (may need some time to understand this one)

```
@Database(entities = {UserLog.class},version = 1)
abstract class UserOnlyDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract UserOnlyDao getUserOnlyDao();

    private static volatile UserOnlyDatabase instance;
    private static volatile User currentUser;

    static UserOnlyDatabase getInstance(Context context, User user) {
        if (user == null) {
            throw  new RuntimeException("Attempt to open Invalid - CANNOT continue");
        }
        if ( currentUser == null || (currentUser.getUserId() != user.getUserId())) {
            if (instance != null) {
                if (instance.isOpen()) {
                    instance.close();
                }
                instance = null;
            }
        }
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,UserOnlyDatabase.class,user.userName+ "_log")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries()
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

- Note this works but has only been tested for a simple sceanrio
- the getInstance method is where the swapping of userlog database is undertaken

Now putting it all together in an activity that demonstrates.

- **Note** for convenience and brevity this runs on the main thread. So no consideration for not running it on the main thread has been included. However, as singletons are used there is probably little that isn't covered, just beware that there may be issues to consider.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static int MAXLOGINATTEMPTS = 5;
    static String TAG = "USERLOGINFO";

    UniversalUserDatabase uniDB;
    UniversalDao uniDao;
    UserOnlyDatabase uoDB;
    UserOnlyDao uoDao;
    User currentUser = new User();
    int loginAttempts = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        uniDB = UniversalUserDatabase.getInstance(this);
        uniDao = uniDB.getAllDao();

        // Add Some Users
        uniDao.insertUser(new User("Fred","password"));
        uniDao.insertUser(new User(Long.valueOf(1000),"Mary","password"));

        // Login to the first user logging the login attempt
        if (forceLogin("Fred","password",true)) {
            Log.d(TAG,currentUser.userName + " successfully logged in.");
            uniDao.insertLog(new UserLog(currentUser,"Logged In Successfully"));

            uoDB = UserOnlyDatabase.getInstance(this,currentUser);
            uoDao = uoDB.getUserOnlyDao();
            uoDao.insertUserLog(new UserLog(currentUser,"UOLogged in was Good"));
        }
        // Write the logs to the log for Universal and userOnly approach
        logCurrentUserLog();
        logUserOnlyLog();

        // SWITCH USER and database for User Only approach logging login to the logs
        if (forceLogin("Mary","password",true)) {
            Log.d(TAG,currentUser.userName + " successfully logged in.");
            uniDao.insertLog(new UserLog(currentUser,"Logged in Successfuly"));

            uoDB = UserOnlyDatabase.getInstance(this,currentUser);
            uoDao = uoDB.getUserOnlyDao();
            uoDao.insertUserLog(new UserLog(currentUser,"UOLogged in was Good"));
        }
        logCurrentUserLog();
        logUserOnlyLog();
    }

    private boolean addUser(String userName, String password) {
        return uniDao.insertUser(new User(userName,password)) > 0;
    }

    private boolean login(String userName, String password) {
        long userId;
        if (++loginAttempts >= MAXLOGINATTEMPTS) return false;
        if (!((userId = uniDao.verifyUserLogin(userName,password)) > 0)) return false;
        currentUser = uniDao.getUserById(userId);
        loginAttempts = 0;
        return true;
    }
    private boolean forceLogin(String userName, String password, boolean crashIfTooManyAttempts) {
        while (!login(userName,password)) {
            if (loginAttempts >= MAXLOGINATTEMPTS) {
                if (crashIfTooManyAttempts)
                     throw new RuntimeException("Too Many Login Attempts - Goodbye");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    private void logCurrentUserLog() {
        for(UserLog ul: uniDao.getUserLogs(currentUser.getUserId())) {
            Log.d(TAG,ul.timestamp + " User = " + currentUser.userName + "Log = " + ul.logData);
        }
    }

    private void logUserOnlyLog() {
        for(UserLog ul: uoDao.getUserLogs()) {
            Log.d(TAG + "_UO",ul.timestamp + " UO ID = " +ul.userId + " " + ul.id + ul.logData);
        }
    }
}
```

So this :-

1. Gets an instance of the Universal Database and gets the Dao.
2. Adds 2 users Fred and Mary (Mary with an id forced to be 1000 just for show, makes no difference to the demo what Mary's id is)
   1.Logs on to Fred writing.
3. A login entry is added for Fred in the Universal Database log.
4. An instance of Fred's UserOnly database is obtained and a login entry is made in Fred's log in Fred's database.
5. Fred's log entries, from the Universal database, are output to the Device's log.
6. Fred's log entries from his personal database are output to the Device's log.
7. **USER is SWITCHED to Mary** when Mary log's on.
8. A login entry is added for Mary in the Universal Database Log.
9. An instance of Mary's UserOnly database is obtained and a login entry is made in Mary's log in Mary's database.
10. Mary's  log entries. from the Universal Database Log are output to the Device's log.
11. **NOTE** Fred's entries **ARE NOT output** even though they exist in the Log..
12. Mary's log entries from his personal database are output to the Device's log.

**Results**

The Device's Log after the first run :-

```
2021-04-18 13:38:18.381 D/USERLOGINFO: Fred successfully logged in.
2021-04-18 13:38:18.412 D/USERLOGINFO: 1618717098382 User = FredLog = Logged In Successfully
2021-04-18 13:38:18.415 D/USERLOGINFO_UO: 1618717098385 UO ID = 1 1UOLogged in was Good
2021-04-18 13:38:18.419 D/USERLOGINFO: Mary successfully logged in.
2021-04-18 13:38:18.453 D/USERLOGINFO: 1618717098419 User = MaryLog = Logged in Successfuly
2021-04-18 13:38:18.457 D/USERLOGINFO_UO: 1618717098429 UO ID = 1000 1UOLogged in was Good
```

The database's via Database Inspector

Showing the Universal Database Log (recommended apporaoch) :-

[image]

- As Fred's database was closed this is shown as closed

Showing The UserOnly log (Mary's) :-

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the helpful response! By the way, what software are you using to visually see the DB?

Comment: @OrLevi That's viewed with Android Studio's Database Inspector. https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/#4.2-db-inspector

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to implement the universal DB method as you said, but i'm having trouble understanding what exactly happenes after Mary logs in. All of Fred's information is still stored in the universal DB, but I wanted for Mary to see only her information and not Fred's.

Comment: @OrLevi With that way you filter what the user sees so `@Query("SELECT * FROM log WHERE userId=:userId") List<UserLog> getUserLogs(long userId);` is saying only show the log for the userid that is passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can shoud clear your databases every time a users logs out:

```
YourDataBase.getInstance(context).clearTables()
```

Comment: But if the first user logs in again the DB will be empty, and that's not what I want.